# Facebook PHP api: wall/action links redirecting back to FB?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I've got an FB app that's publishing to a user's timeline, and also publishing an action to the user's aggregated activity box. All is working and publishing fine, but if I click on a published link to bring the viewer back to the app (which is a standalone site), it's going to the site quickly, and redirecting straight back to FB. Has anyone else seen this?

Note on the site

- It's a website with a FB login
- Auth referrals are turned OFF
- The OG actions have not been submitted yet
- Everything else is working fine.

Here's what I'm doing to post to FB using the PHP API and Codeigniter:

```
    $object             = "[object]";
    $url                = base_url().'home/index/unique_url_for_object';
    $namespace      = "[namespace]";
    $action             = "[action]";

    $params = array($object=>$url, 'access_token'=>$this->facebook->getAccessToken());

    $post_id = $this->facebook->api('/me/'.$namespace.':'.$action,'post',$params);
```

.. every clickable link on FB redirects back to FB when it's supposed to point back at my site!!

Has anyone else seen this, or could you possibly point out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,
PaulG

Comment: Could you try this again without the access_token parameter, cause it looks like you are using the PHP SDK of Facebook which attaches the same to all the requests. And also try doing the same with [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

Comment: Hi Anvesh, I did that, and tried again - no joy. The redirection back to FB is still occurring. I see what you mean though, but it has nothing to do with the redirection from FB - the access token is obviously used to allow me to post to FB, which is all working fine. Weirdly, it's redirecting to http://www.facebook.com/home.php#_=_  - any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe you did it but I just wanted to make sure if you added the required tags of the object on your object's page also.